# Technique for using a wide background div without affecting body width

Tags: html, css, layout

Please reference this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/Fcznp/) with the following explanation:

I have a web page with an extra-wide, centered background image.  I want the body width of the page to collapse to the content, and ignore the div that contains the background.  In the given example, I have a simplified example of how I do this: An bg-outer div establishes the proper page width (200px wide), and an bg-inner div (400px wide) contains the extra-wide image.  I then use overflow:visible and negative margins to attempt to center the wider bg-inner without increasing the page width.  However, as the example shows, horizontal scrollbars appear when the browser window is less than 400px, not 200px.  Why does this happen?  Is there a better approach?

Thanks-

**EDIT:**

Here's a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4039219/making-a-div-that-sits-outside-the-content-area-but-doesnt-cause-the-horizontal/4039327#4039327) I ended up finding, with a similiar though slightly different solution.  I like the answer wdm gives here better though.

Comment: "I want the body width of the page to collapse to the content, and ignore the div that contains the background." Could you please clarify?

Comment: I want my page width to be recognized as 200px, so that h-scrollbars will only show up if the browser is smaller than that.  I want this to happen even though I'm working with a background image that is 400px wide. (Sizes are relative to the example.  In reality, I'm working with a page 960px wide, with a background image that is 1400px+ wide. That image is centered, with its sides usually cutoff unless browser is expanded).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Duplicate post: [Why do negative margins affect my page width?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690020/why-do-negative-margins-affect-my-page-width)

However this one explains better what you're trying to accomplish.

This is simple...

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wdm954/L3U9c/

```
<div id="bg">
    <div id="content">
        Here is my content.
    </div>
</div>


#bg {
    background-color: red;
    background-position: top center; /* for images */
}
#content {   
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    position: relative;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: #ccc;
}
```

Comment: @wdm- You are a scholar and a gentleman- this elegant solution works perfectly- thanks

Comment: @wdm if the browser width is less than 200px, the background image stays centered, even though the left side of the content remains flush with the left side of the view pane. I have a similar problem, but I need the background image to stay locked to wherever the content div is, but not display scrollbars in the bg div is wider than the view pane.

Answer (score 0):

You can add

```
body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Comment: I don't see it in the example. I tried before and after adding the lines I posted and noticed the scrollbars had gone.

Comment: @Fareesh- my bad, you're right it wasn't in the previous example, but still doesn't fit my solution- overflow:hidden would hide the overflow- I want to show the overflow, but ignore it with respect to layout.

Answer (score 0):

I think all you need for what you're doing is 3 lines of CSS:

```
body {
    background-image:url('myurl.jpg');
    background-position:center;
    background-size:cover;
}
```

As you can see:

```
<body>
    <p>This is my document. Nothing else necessary</p>
    <!-- any other content you desire -->
</body>
```

Comment: @ninjagecko- Thanks, but this won't work for my situation- fixed width background with y-repeating- Trying to figure out how to ignore the actual div width in the example...