# Why do negative margins affect my page width?

Tags: html, css, layout

Please reference the following [example](http://jsfiddle.net/wdm954/Fcznp/9/):

In it, an outer div 200px wide is meant to establish our page width.  It contains an inner div 400px wide, but with left/right negative margins of -100px.

My intended end result is that the  browser register total content width at 200px, not 400px, but horizontal scrollbars show up as soon as the window is resized to less than 400px.  What is going on here?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by having the inner div wider than the outer div?

Comment: @wdm- It started with the a background centering problem I posed here (Which you solved), but I posed this as a more theoretical question, wanting to better understand layout principles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gareth's answer is correct. Even with negative margin, the div is still part of the standard page flow and will not be ignored with respect to layout. Genuine page content cannot be ignored for scrolling purposes.

However, if you're doing this for an aesthetic, such as having a shadow down the sides of the page that extends beyond your max width, this can be achieved with a background - [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4039219/making-a-div-that-sits-outside-the-content-area-but-doesnt-cause-the-horizontal) should help.

Answer (score 2):

Negative margins don't adjust the width of the `div`. A negative left margin will move the `div` to the left of it's position in the flow of the page, and a negative right margin will allow other elements to overlap the right hand side of the `div` by the amount of the margin.

You can hopefully see what I mean in [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vEk8p/).

From your question it sounds like you need `overflow: hidden` to contain a large `div` within a smaller one without spilling out of its boundaries.

Comment: @Gareth- overflow:hidden hides the overflow- I want the overflow visible, but ignored with respect to layout.

Answer (score 1):

as Gareth already mentioned, margins do not affect the box size. The solution is rather simple. The outer container needs to be 400px, this is what is going to trigger the horizontal scroll bars. The inner container needs to be 200px with 100px left and right margins. When you resize the window, the scroll bars appear as soon as you have gotten smaller than the outer container.

http://jsfiddle.net/58VFB/

Comment: @Brent- That's not what I'm trying to accomplish. The whole point is I want the scrollbars to trigger only at the 200px width, and be ignored for the 400px width, though looks like this might be impossible...

Comment: Umm. Why set anything to 400px then? If you want scrollbars at 200px only, then make the wrapper that size. You should update your questions so it does not say you want them at 400px so anyone else that sees this doesn't get confused.

Comment: @Brent- It's for the sake of having an overflowing background that doesn't affect the layout.  In any case, I'm not looking for an alternative solution, just an explanation of how neg margins affect the layout in this case.

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your CSS...

```
body {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow: -moz-scrollbars-vertical;
}
```